# How to use the cookie from an http response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, cookies

I work in react on a front-end app which make API request.

The authentication route return an sid in response but also a cookie,
when I go to the network part of firefox I see the cookie and its value.

[image]

Is it possible to access this cookie in js/react ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
    const cookieValue = (`; ${document?.cookie}`).split('; cookie_consent=').pop().split(';')[0];
```

I am using this in chrome, here please update your key with 'cookie_consent', This might work!.

Comment: The cookie isn"t stock in cookie storage actually, I don't know how to put it in

Comment: You can put like this,
    document.cookie = 'cookie_consent=true; expires=Fri, 31 Dec 9999 23:59:59 GMT Secure';

Again Replace your key with cookie_consent, I hope it will help you.